# Событие вкладки и окна браузера

Tags: javascript

Необходимо отследить это событие.

Нужно это для прочтения сообщений в диалогах aka *Диалоги во ВКонтакте*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visibility.js](http://habrahabr.ru/company/evilmartians/blog/125833/), не?